# How to generate JSON in PostgreSQL with conditional keys

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am generating JSON using a query that looks like this

```
SELECT 
    json_build_object(
        'key1', t1.field1,
        'key2', t1.field2,
        'key3', t1.field3
    )
FROM table1 as t1
WHERE ...
```

and I get results that look like this

`{"key1": 123, "key2": "some string", "key3": 100}`

or like this

`{"key1": 123, "key2": "some string", "key3": null}`

What I need is a way to make the second example drop the whole key instead of including the null value. That is, I want to somehow omit key3 when the value in field3 is null. And end up with this JSON

`{"key1": 123, "key2": "some string"}`

How do I go about this? I am running PostgreSQL 9.4, so some JSON operations are not available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT json_object_agg(name, value)
     FROM (VALUES
        ('key1', to_json(t1.field1)),
        ('key2', to_json(t1.field2)),
        ('key3', to_json(t1.field3))
        ) AS props(name, value)
     WHERE value IS NOT NULL
    ) AS json
FROM table1 as t1
WHERE ...
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I run into a type problem in the values clause, since field1, field2 and field3 are different types. `VALUES types character, varying and integer cannot be matched`

Comment: @MadWombat ah, if your fields have different types then you'll need to cast them to `json` beforehand. Or just do the filtering afterwards like in @Klin's answer